# Pegar o item selecionado do plugin Select2 e fazer um Submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

Como pegar o item selecionado do plugin DropDownList **Select2** (https://plugins.jquery.com/select2/), e enviar para um Controler através de um button submit ?

**TELA**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**CONTROLER**

```
public ActionResult Index(ContratoViewModel contratoViewModel)
{
int id = contratoViewModel.Id;
}
```

**BOTÃO QUE FAZ O SUBMIT**

```
 <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Buscar" type="submit" id="btnBuscar" />
```

**HTML**

```
    @using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "Contrato", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <label>Cliente</label><br />
                <select id="ClienteID" name="ClienteID" class="form-control">
                    <option value="0">[SELECIONE]</option>
                </select>
            </div>
<div class="col-xs-3">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ContratoViewModel.NumeroContrato)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ContratoViewModel.NumeroContrato, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-3">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ContratoViewModel.Responsavel)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ContratoViewModel.Responsavel, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-2">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ContratoViewModel.Status)<br />
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.ContratoViewModel.Status, "true", new { @checked = "checked" }) Ativo
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.ContratoViewModel.Status, "false") Inativo
        </div>
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script src="~/Content/Scripts/select2.full.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#ClienteID").select2({
            allowClear: true,
            ajax: {
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/Contrato/ListarClienteJSON',
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        pNome: params.term
                    };
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                processResults: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: data
                    };
                }
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adriano, dá uma olhada na minha resposta em:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/108564/21263

Observe o *callback do javascript*. Ao retornar os valores, ele deverá preencher *hidden field* com o código do cliente. No MVC, o *hidden field* estará linkado ao Model. Você precisa colocar o callback no seu código para preencher o *hidden field* e, consequentemente, sua model.

```
<input type="hidden" id="CodigoDoCliente" 
                     name="CodigoDoCliente" 
                     value="@Model.CodigoDoCliente" />
```

O callback:

```
initSelection: function (element, callback) {
            var id = $(element).val();
            if (id) {
                var url = '@Url.Action("ListarClienteJSON", "Cliente")';
                $.ajax(url + '/' + id, {
                    dataType: "json"
                }).done(function (data) {
                    callback({ 'id': id, 'text': $('#Nome').val() })
                });
            } else {
                callback({ 'id': $('#IdDoCliente').val(), 'text': $('#Nome').val() })
            }
        }
```

Quando você clicar no botão buscar, a Model já conterá o código do seu cliente e o método do seu controlador receberá a informação necessária.

ContratoController:

```
public ActionResult Index(ContratoViewModel contratoViewModel)
{
   return View();
}
```

ClienteController:

```
public JsonResult ListarClienteJSON(Int32? idCliente)
{
  List<Cliente> clientes;

  if (idCliente.HasValue)
  {
    clientes = _clientesBSS.obterCliente(c => c.ID == idCliente.Value);
  }
  else 
  {    
    clientes = _clientesBSS.obterClientes().ToList();
  }

  return Json(clientes.Select(c => new
  {
     Id = c.ID,
     Nome = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.Nome) ? "" : c.Nome
  }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```